# ASP sumar datos de columnas

Tags: html, sql, asp

tengo una tabla en donde e uan columna me muestra los diferentes porcentajes obtenidos de la asistencia mensual , pero quiero obtener mi asistencia anual en porcentaje , osea sumar todos los porcentajes que llevo hasta el momento

```
<div class="row-fluid">
<div class="span12"style="overflow-y:auto;">
    <h1 class="text-center" style="margin-bottom:1em;"><strong>Porcentaje Personal Capacitado</strong></h1>
    <table id="lista" class="table table-hover table-bordered bootstrap-datatable datatable dataTable">
        <caption></caption>
        <thead>
            <tr>
                <th>Mes</th>
                <th>Año</th>
                <th>Personal</th>
                <th>% mensual de capacitacion</th>

            </tr>
        </thead>
        <tbody>

<%      for i = lbound(datos ,2) to ubound(datos ,2)%>

            <tr>

                <td><%=i+1%></td>
                <td><%=datos(1,i)%></td>
                <td><%=datos(2,i)%></td>
                <td><%=round((datos(2,i)*100)/datos(3,i),2)%>%</td>
                <!--F Registro-->


            </tr>
  <%        next %>
        </tbody>
    </table>
   </div>
</div>
```

[image: Tabla]

quiero  mostrar al final de la tabla en una fila en resultado pero no se como sumar todos los datos , hay alguna forma de realizarlo en ASP .Gracias

Answer (score 0):

Podrías hacerlo acumulando en una variable la suma de todo lo que vas mostrando en la última columna, y posteriormente, cuando acabas de ejecutar el bucle, mostrar una nueva fila con el resultado:

```
<%      
dim resultadoFinal
```

resultadoFinal = 0

for i = lbound(datos ,2) to ubound(datos ,2)
    resultadoFinal = resultadoFinal + (round((datos(2,i)*100)/datos(3,i),2))

```
%>

        <tr>

            <td><%=i+1%></td>
            <td><%=datos(1,i)%></td>
            <td><%=datos(2,i)%></td>
            <td><%=round((datos(2,i)*100)/datos(3,i),2)%>%</td>
            <!--F Registro-->


        </tr>


  <%        next %>


<tr>
<td>TOTAL</td>
<td>&nbsp;</td>
<td>&nbsp;</td>
<td><%=round(resultadoFinal, 2)%>%</td>

</tr>
```

Espero que te sirva.